# Do we want code review questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked [a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260482/84737) on CodeReview, and the answerer suggested:

> P.S. In the future, please ask questions on StackOverflow, as more people are monitoring it, than StackExchange.

I presume we don't want code review questions on SO (which is why I asked on CR in the first place)?

Comment: IMO, ignore that P.S., questions can be on topic in multiple places, you asked it in the one where it made most sense to you. Ask the question where you think it would be best received, just because SO has more active users doesn't mean you'd get the kind of response you'd like. In my eyes, the post is clearly on topic on CR.

Comment: That PS is total BS... Don't take too seriously any comment around. It actually makes no sense as they refer to CodeReview as StackExchange and what does it mean *"In the future ask questions on SO"*? All of them? Even if they're about the meaning of life?

Comment: The PS has been removed by a high-rep user by the way.

Comment: if you can't get an answer on the other sides, you can try your luck on SO, if it is on On topic

Comment: "*and the answerer suggested*" the answerer who still has "New User" flag under their name? Are you sure they are the most reliable source of information about policy?

Comment: @VLAZ They're new on Code Review but seem to be a long time member on Stack Overflow (8 years and 2 months). But still, their advice was rather wrong.

Comment: @Clockwork the advice is given on CR, and such should be related to a CR policy. I've few years of experience on SO but I wouldn't try to give policy advice on, say, Ubuntu.

Comment: "more people are monitoring it" is *not* a reason to ask on SO instead of CR. Ask wherever the question is *appropriate*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi very good point. Otherwise we wouldn't need any other sites - the most people are monitoring SO. Actually, if we follow this premise to its logical conclusion, we should also close SO, because more people are monitoring Facebook, for example.

Comment: @VLAZ Hmm... I was thinking that, since they're trying to give a policy about Stack Overflow, what would matter would be their "seniority" on the targeted site, rather than the site on which they posted. But yeah, I see your point.

Comment: @VLAZ Now there's a migration target I could have needed in the past... ;)

Comment: The PS has been removed by a high-rep CR user. Additionally had I seen the PS I would have removed the PS too. We (Code Review) and you (Stack Overflow) get some users who give out bad advice, normally in comments. Like "post on {site}", where {site} won't accept the question. Don't believe everything a low rep users says; the user doesn't even have VTC privileges on either site.

Answer (score 19):

***NO.*** We don't want code reviewing questions here.

Stack Overflow is intended to be a library of useful programming questions with their answers for generations to come. Questions like *"How can I improve/shorten this code"* are ***NOT*** helpful to anyone except the person asking it - that's not the purpose of SO. No one will search for that title in a search engine, and even if someone happens to search that, what are the chances that they have the exact same code?

You *could* potentially break down a Code Review question to several Stack Overflow questions, each focusing on a specific part of your program which could benefit others without the context of your complete program.

There is a small overlap of questions that could exist in both sites and it's important to note that *"this question belongs on Code Review"* is ***NOT*** a close reason. Most chances are that a code reviewing question is going to be too broad and *that* will be the close reason. If it doesn't apply, then the question might be suitable for SO.

Answer (score -8):

If the answerer suggested you jump off a cliff, would you have done it?

If you'd [taken the CR tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), which states:

> Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code

would you have posted this question?

Comment: [Perhaps](https://xkcd.com/1170/).

Comment: This does not answer the question: Do we want code review questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I have taken the CR tour, and the SO one - but being a valid question for CR doesn't preclude it being valid here also